# Automated deployment of JavaScript project for different environments

Tags: java, javascript, maven, automation, continuous-integration

I was looking for similar problems and, of course, there exists many but I would like to know if someone uses a similar project like us and how you have deal with it.

We are working on a project where:
- Client side is completely based on JavaScript, with Dojo Toolkit framework, which makes AJAX request to our server side.
- Server side based on Java+Spring+Hibernate which implements some REST API.

We are managin the two parts as different projects, that is, for the server side we are using maven and for each change our CI server runs tests.
The important step here is we can configura maven with profiles so the CI can create a package ready for pre-production or production environments using different property files.

The client side is a bunch (with a nice structure) of HTML, CSS and JavaScript files. Like the server side, on the client side we have property file to point the client to the right place (like the development server side).

The question is: which could be the best way on this scenario to automate the client side?development? I mean, run JavaScript tests on CI and autodeploy to the right environment using the appropriate property file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While someone gives you a proper and complete answer you might want to have a look at a similar question I did. [Javascript web app and Java server, build all in Maven or use Grunt for web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406977/javascript-web-app-and-java-server-build-all-in-maven-or-use-grunt-for-web-app)

I am trying different options out there but most probably we will finish using Grunt for the client side. Maven exec to call it and build everything (client + server) with different profiles.